# is the force keep the same ratio using 2 pulleys not vertically align

Tags: forces

I have a system with 2 pulleys which are not on the same axis. I am trying to figure out if the force at the 2 extremities are the same. Normally with 1 mobile pulley I got a ratio of 2, but in my case I don't think I got 2 but I also don't think it's the same...

So basically is F1 = F2 in my picture ?

Thank you very much
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the pulleys are smooth and the string is light and inextensible then the tension is constant all the way along the string.

Comment: Thank you for you help